# Where should I put my Azure ServiceBus listener

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I have created a ServiceBus listener, and it works fine; the problem is deciding where to put it. It's now located in one of my APIs, but when the API is not in use the listener stops listening. I assume that's because of the application lifetime, and that the API is not running when it's not in use.

Can you provide me guidance on how and where to place the Azure ServiceBus listener so that it runs all the time and never goes down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a Worker Role running in a Cloud Service. A Worker Role is  basically a VM wrapped around your code.

[.NET Multi-Tier Application Using Service Bus Queues](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-using-service-bus-queues/) should get you going.